# How to insert into a 2d std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap

I am trying to insert data into a 2d map but the following code gives me a Access violation error.

```
void StateManager::AddState(string stateName, map<string, IBaseComponent*> stateComponents)
{
    // Add the state to the states map
    m_States.insert(pair<string, map<string, IBaseComponent*>>(stateName,stateComponents));
}
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it ?

Edit: I tried inserting some test values into the map and that works fine. Must be a problem with the data I am inserting.

Comment: show the type of `m_States`. a `>` is missing, so it shouldn't even compile. please show *real* compileable, minimal code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: `pair<string, map<string, IBaseComponent*>` has an unmatched angular bracket

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. missing >

Comment: Added the > to the post. I properly didn't copy the code right... The code compiles but the problem is the access violation error.

Comment: no, the problem is we have no idea what the rest of your code does. Please come up with a *minimal* example which actually compiles.

Comment: Yes you are right should have done that in the first place. Made a example with test data and it works fine. So the problem doesn't have anything to do with the map insert but the data that I am inserting.

Comment: Isn't it "m_States.insert(pair< **stateName**, map<string, IBaseComponent*>>(stateName,stateComponents)); ?

Comment: Nope the syntax is right. It turns out I was using the function before initializing the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the function before initializing the object that contains it. So m_States wasn't actually created yet. Hence the access violation error.